# django send email recipient_list

Tags: python, django, email

I need to get the email registered in the database and send to this email that is registered, but I can not.
If I put an email manually it is sending without problems, but I need it to get the email that is registered in Pessoa to use in MovRotativo to send the payment as soon as it is done

erro
"TypeError at /sistema/mov-rot-novo/
object of type 'Pessoa' has no len()"

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
import math
PAGO_CHOICES = (
('Não', 'Não Pago'),
('Sim', 'Pago')
)

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nome) + ' - ' + str(self.email) 

class MovRotativo(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=False,)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    valor_hora = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(
        Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)

    def send_email(self):
        if self.pago == 'Sim':

            send_mail(
                'Comprovante pagamento Estacione Aqui 24 Horas',
                'Here is the message.',
                'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com',
                recipient_list=[self.email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Comment: Is the email supposed to be sent after a user checks out?

Comment: in fact it must be sent after it has made the payment from No to Yes
But it could be in the chekout without problems

Answer (score 0):

In `MovRotativo`, `email` is not an `EmailField` but an instance of class `Pessoa`. You want the `email` from the `Pessoa`, which is `email.email`:

```
recipient_list=[self.email.email],
```

Comment: @MauricioKalfelz Remember that you have two objects you are working with (a `MovRotativo` and its associated `Pessoa`), and you need to read from both of them and update both of them. I think this new problem might be better investigated as a second question, if my answer solved your original problem.

Comment: already abusing his help.
I wanted to put in the body of the message the chekin and chekout plus a def called valor_total that I have

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the object email since email is **Pessoa** and you are naming it email so.. since you are doing a join to get the email... you need to reference it. using **email.email** as it would be **Pessoa.email** hope it helps. I also aded an extra line for validating that the email isn't empty.

```
class MovRotativo(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=False,)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    valor_hora = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(
        Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)

    def send_email(self):
        if self.pago == 'Sim':
            if email.email:
                send_mail(
                    'Comprovante pagamento Estacione Aqui 24 Horas',
                    'Here is the message.',
                    'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com',
                    recipient_list=[self.email.email],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
```